# radiobutton with ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i m doing a project on "student attendance management system".i using rail of version 1.9.1
and rail of version 2.5. i wanted to use radiobutton in my project to mark present and absent so how can i use?please send me the code and what should i do? if you want to give any suggetion so i will very happy.

Comment: I removed your email address. Answers to questions on Stackoverflow belong on Stackoverflow.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a send-me-code kind of site.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from the [rails api docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#M002299):

> radio_button(object_name, method,
>   tag_value, options = {})
>
> Returns a radio button tag for
>   accessing a specified attribute
>   (identified by method) on an object
>   assigned to the template (identified
>   by object). If the current value of
>   method is tag_value the radio button
>   will be checked.
>
> To force the radio button to be
>   checked pass :checked => true in the
>   options hash. You may pass HTML
>   options there as well. Examples
>
> ```
> # Let's say that @student.attendance returns "rails":
> radio_button("student", "attendance", "present")
> radio_button("student", "attendance", "absent")
> # => <input type="radio" id="student_attendance_present" name="student[attendance]" value="present" checked="checked" />
> #    <input type="radio" id="student_attendance_absent" name="student[attendance]" value="absent" />
>
> radio_button("user", "receive_newsletter", "yes")
> radio_button("user", "receive_newsletter", "no")
> # => <input type="radio" id="user_receive_newsletter_yes" name="user[receive_newsletter]" value="yes" />
> #    <input type="radio" id="user_receive_newsletter_no" name="user[receive_newsletter]" value="no" checked="checked" />
> ```